# Getting a variable from a list of div inside for loop to onClick()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i am trying to make a calendar and simply select a day (which is a ) to change its css class, having a reactjs class based component with daySelected as a state prop.

inside createCalendar() i get the day number using an indicator (date) and i increment it inside the for loop, having onClick() to pass the date to handleClick(date).

When i select any day i always get the last day as selected.

I want to have pass the variable date to handelClick(date) from the selected day, please suggest any solution.

ps : i need to make everthing inside a single component to control the state prop daySelected

```
 handleClick = day => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      checked: !state.checked,
      daySelected: day
    }));
  };

createCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear) {
        let firstDay = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth).getDay();
        let daysInMonth =
          32 - new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, 32).getDate() - 1;
        var days = [];
        let date = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (i === 0 && j < firstDay) {
              var x = (
                <div className={"Day"}>
                  <p> </p>
                </div>
              );
            } else if (date > daysInMonth) {
              break;
            } else {
              date++;



              var x = (

                 // I want to get the variable date from here  

                <div
                  value={date}
                  onClick={() => this.handleClick(date)}
                  className={this.state.daySelected == date ? "Day-checked" : "Day"}
                >
                  <p>{date}</p>
                </div>
              );
            }

            days.push(x);
          }
        }
        return days;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwritting a `x` value in a loop (using one reference), you should use a function.

Just convert subcomponent definition to a function, sth like `const x = (date) => {...` and use it in a loop.